# How make two inputs with Material Dialog

Tags: android, material-design

[Material Dialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs#input-dialogs)

So well that es my code.. add two inputs in my Material Dialog and have this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk0z1.png)

```
MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title(R.string.ingresar_codigo)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
                .input(getString(R.string.codigo), "1", new MaterialDialog.InputCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInput(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                        datos[0] = input.toString();
                        Log.d(TAG, datos[0]);
                    }
                })
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
                .input(getString(R.string.dni), "2", new MaterialDialog.InputCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInput(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                        datos[1] = input.toString();
                        Log.d(TAG, datos[1]);
                    }
                })
                .positiveText(R.string.aceptar)
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        if (!datos[0].isEmpty() && !datos[1].isEmpty()) {
                            confirmarDialogoDatos(datos[0], datos[1], MenuCorporativo.this);
                        } else { Snackbar.make(layout, "DEBE INGRESAR DATOS", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
                    }
                })
                .negativeText(R.string.cancelar)
                .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

I have a problem not like having two EditText in my material dialog

Comment: I think you must use dialog with your customized layout, because default one have only 1 input field. Read the docs for details.

Comment: it's ok. should add edittext with code ? like a alertdialog ?

Comment: No, use customized layout with 2 `EditText`-s you need.

Comment: ok ty for u answer : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom layout with 2 EditText

```
boolean wrapInScrollView = true;
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
        .title(R.string.title)
        .customView(R.layout.custom_view, wrapInScrollView)
        .positiveText(R.string.positive)
        .show();

MaterialDialog dialog = //... initialization via the builder ...
View view = dialog.getCustomView();
view.findViewById(R.id.edittext1)
view.findViewById(R.id.edittext2)
```